# How to select a row's text from a UITableView Xamarin.ios c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am wanting to select the text from a row in my table, I've done some searching but I can't seem to find an example in Xamarin.ios I think that I am wanting something similar to this

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
}
```

but in Xamarin.ios instead of objective c, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
     new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
     tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // iOS convention is to remove the highlight
}
```

All you need is the row index (indexPath.Row )and you can get the text from the Array that fills you UITableView

From Xamarin website on how to [Handle Row Click](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/handle_a_row_click/)